# SharePoint designer 2013 will not install

Tags: 2013, designer

Using a clean install of Win 10 Pro. Install of O365 2016 desktop apps (downloaded from O365 Admin portal) went fine, but attempts to install SharePoint Designer 2013, InfoPath 2013, Visio 2013, and Project 2013 all failed. Each show the following error:

[image: Error]

Visio version: en_visio_professional_2013_x86_1123796

Project version: ProjectProfessional_x86_en-us

All office installs are 32 bit

Any suggestions on how to install the above?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

If you have office installed make sure it is also 32bits, other wise you will need to install SP designer 64bits.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of which to install (32 or 64 bit) relies on what edition of Office you have (32 or 64 bit), and it has to match.

Comment: All office installs are 32 bit as described above in the post